# (python3:19): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:20:11.494: gst_value_init_and_copy: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (src)' failed

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer, nvidia-deepstream, deepstream

i get this message `(python3:19): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:20:11.494: gst_value_init_and_copy: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (src)' failed` after running deepstream for couple of minutes. can someone please tell me why this message is shown?

This message is not shown when i increase drop frame interval. Is the buffer getting filled?

Comment: There's no way of knowing what's happening without the accompanying code. You can try running the executable with gdb and the envvar G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals to see where the problem exactly happens